# Print string to file, only parts of the string got printed

Tags: excel, vba

I've made an application where you create projects. Every time you create a project it's saved in a text file on a network hard drive.

The projects are stored in a long string like so:

```
PROJECT1 Chr(17) Name Chr(17) Status Chr(17) CreationDate Chr(17) Comments Chr(18) _
PROJECT2 Chr(17) Name Chr(17) Status Chr(17) CreationDate Chr(17) Comments Chr(18) _
PROJECT3 Chr(17) Name Chr(17) Status Chr(17) CreationDate Chr(17) Comments Chr(18) _
PROJECT4 Chr(17) Name Chr(17) Status Chr(17) CreationDate Chr(17) Comments
```

Just an example, the real projects have about 60 variables stored in them.

All the projects are separated using Chr(18) and the data belonging to the projects are separated using Chr(17).

When you open a project the long string is split using Chr(18) as the delimiter. Then a for loop loops through all the projects until it finds the one you wanted to open. It then takes that one and split it using Chr(17) as a delimiter to get all the data. Like so:

```
Projects = Split(TextFile, Chr(18))
For i = 0 to UBound(Projects)
    If Left(Projects, 8) = ProjectToOpen Then
        ProjectData = Split(Projects(i), Chr(17))
        CurrentProject = i
        Exit For
    End If 
Next i
```

The data is then added to cells in a worksheet.

```
ws.Range("E1") = ProjectData(1)
ws.Range("G6") = ProjectData(2)
....
....
etc. etc.
```

When the user is changing a cell, the value of that cell is replacing the value in the text file. All the data and arrays are joined into a long string and that is printed in one go. Like so:

```
Sub PrintData(DataToChange As Integer, CurrentRow As Integer, CurrentColumn As Integer, _
              CurrentProject As Integer, ProjectData() As String, Projects() As String, _
              PathToTextFile As String, ws As Worksheet)

    Dim TextFile As String

    ProjectData(DataToChange) = ws.cells(CurrentRow, CurrentColumn).Value
    Projects(CurrentProject) = Join(ProjectData, Chr(17))
    TextFile = Join(Projects, Chr(18))

    On Error GoTo NoPath
    Open PathToTextFile For Output As #1
        Print #1, TextFile
    Close #1
    On Error GoTo 0
NoPath:
    Close #1
```

There are multiple users working with this app. They are all reading and printing to this text file.

Now, someone entered data in one of the cells and all the data after the changed data got lost. All the data up until the new change was saved, the rest wasn't. The text file got chopped in half. A lot of data got lost. I do know that the user was pasting data from a webpage into the cell.
Maybe there was a special character in there that stopped the Printing?

Anyone have an idea what could have happened?

Comment: You only show a part of your code, which I do not think can create the problem you try explaining. **How the `ProjectInfo` array is loaded**? Is the code you are talking about in an event (`Sheet_Change`)? How the errors are handled in the respective code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added more info to the question. I have error handling when loading or printing data. Basically if the ```Open``` statement doesn't work is shows a msgbox. "Can't connect to data" All the other errors that occurs are unhandled (the standard VBA popup happens) Users then notify me of the error and I do the debugging.

Comment: I cannot say that I can follow the logic of your process completely. However, one thing: You read only *one* line from the file. If a user entered data with a line break into a cell and you write the content to the file, the next time your read the file, all content after that newline is *not* read. So probably, after the next write to the file, the content is gone.

Comment: That's interesting, that would explain it perfectly. There was a line break in the content written to the cell when the error happened. Though there's a lot of chr(10) in the string and it opens fully every time. The users are told to use Alt+Enter when typing several lines into a cell. And it have worked beautifully for months. And the cell that the user copied the info from, its info was loaded from the .txt file. So if that cell contained characters that would cause a line break then the data would be gone days ago. The info in that cell was entered six days ago.

Comment: I also tried to replicate the error by copying that exact cell into the new cell and hit enter and this time the data was saved fully. So I couldn't replicate the error.

Comment: As suggested above, your problem may come from that `Chr(10)` introduced when users "use Alt+Enter when typing several lines into a cell". I mean, all the content after the cell containing such a string will be passed on the next line. And your code finds the appropriate line by finding `ProjectNumber ` as the sixth character. Try looking to the following text file line. The missing characters may be there. Try the next scenario, please: 1. write on a page line whatever in some cell and in one of them (in the middle of the range) then select it.

Comment: 2. Writhe the next testing code: `Dim arr: arr = Selection.Value` `Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(arr)), Chr(18))`. You will see in `Immediate Window` the result. Everything after that 'special' cell it is passed on the next line (eventually, lines, if more such `Chr(10)` exists)... So, next time when the code runs it will use only the line filled **up to the respective cell(s)**, but it should not be lost/gone. I think you may find it in the next code line(s), not having the appropriate sixth character. It will be a little difficult to insert in the right place.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Might be a language barrier. But if the Line looks like this ```000132Chr(18)000012Chr(17)BWait until we clear the orderChr(10)before we place a new oneChr(17)FBlueChr(17)M45Chr(18)000013Chr(17)BOrder sentChr(17)FYellowChr(17)M21``` and I  ```Open``` it I get the entire thing in one string. If I ```Split``` it using Chr(18) as a delimiter I get an array of size 2 (0,1,2). This code has been working fine for several months. It's just now the error happened.

Comment: I'm just wondering why Chr(10) would cause a problem now, when it hasn't done that for months.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer. The copied content contained CRLF characters and that stopped the printing.
I added code that replaced CRLF with just LF before printing. (Basically just the Replace function using vbCrLf and vbLf). The LF character doesn't stop the printing but is treated as a line break in the Excel sheet.